# Designing a brushless DC motor:

Tags: dc-motor, brushless-dc-motor, induction-motor

I watched a DIY [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vnjCrLTMGxQ) recently on building a brushless DC motor.  Can someone demonstrate for me how to calculate the max torque & max rpm of that motor based on the components that are used in the video--not by using a dynamometer or any other device to measure the mechanical power/torque or rpm of such a device?  There must be some EE method/s to reverse engineer & use such data to redesign a similar motor to your own specifications.

Comment: Torque is theoretically limited by heat or demagnetization, but may *especially at speed* be limited by the availability of voltage to push enough current through the winding inductance when commutating rapidly.

Answer (score 1):

You can't "reverse engineer" something that was not engineered in the first place. From an engineering point of view, there is nothing of value here. This is a nice demonstration of how to make a motor that works using inexpensive and easily-obtained parts. You can learn something from it, but it is not a good basis for an engineered motor design.

The major flaw in the design is the lack of any effort to design a magnetic circuit. A good motor needs a closed path for magnetic flux through good magnetic materials with an air gap that is as short as possible. You can inexpensively buy used text books that were published 15 or 20 years ago and find on-line engineering course material that will provide a lot more engineering design information that anyone here is likely to post.

Comment: Thanks for responding to my question.  Perhaps 'engineer' wasn't the best word to use.  "design" might have been a better choice.  I imagine the value might be that the motor could be made quite inexpensively.  It appears to have quite a bit of torque for such a small motor.  It could be used for small projects that don't require much of a motor.  I also noticed that an ESC motor controller can be obtained for less than 15$.  What is "magic flux"?  Did you mean to type "magnetic flux?  Isn't there some relatively simple method for calculating the torque & rpm for such a small motor?

Comment: "Magic" flux is what you get when you combine fat fingers with an automagic spelling corrector. I believe that a motor like this works like a permanent magnet synchronous motor. The speed is completely determined by the overall frequency of the ESC output. It would be very difficult to calculate the torque. Look up "prony brake" to see how to measure the torque. Use some flexible steel to make a ring to connect together the external ends of the bolts holding the coils. That should increase the torque.

Comment: Thanks for the "Prony brake" technique reference.  It's quite a clever technique.  Do you know of any physics calculation method that uses the number of stator poles, number of wire turns per stator, stator flux, rotor magnetic flux, etc. to determine the max torque & max rpm at the shaft?

Comment: Speed (RPM) = 120 f (Hz) / p where f is the frequency at which the ESC reverses polarity and p is the number of motor poles, 4 for the motor described. There are two components of torque. The reaction torque is generated between the rotor magnets and the electro-magnets of the stator. The reluctance torque is the result of the rotor magnets being attracted to the bolts. The dimension of the magnets, bolts and the path of the magnetic flux through the air all figure into the torque. I don't know how to calculate the torque.

Comment: Thanks for responding to my question.  Why "120" in your formula if the power source (battery) provides DC power?   Does "...f is the frequency at which the ESC reverses polarity" mean one full sinusoidal cycle (1 positive phase + one negative phase) or does it mean each clocked phase--as in the case of positive (non polar) square wave?

Comment: 120 is 60 seconds per minute X 2 poles per pair. I am assuming that the ESC output is a series of positive pulses followed by a series of negative pulses somewhat approximating a sine wave. The frequency would be the number of complete positive plus negative sequences or simulated full sinusoidal cycles completed per second. The voltage doesn't affect speed except that it must be enough to push enough current through to provide the torque necessary to drive the load at the speed set by the frequency.

Comment: I see 12 screws & 3 separate pieces of laminated wire in the video.  The screws are positioned equally around a plastic cylinder.  Each laminated wire is wound 25 turns around each of 4 screws that are 90° from each other.   Thus when a positive current flows from the ESR into one laminated series circuit, 2 magnetically 'positive' poles (180° from each other) are created & 2 magnetically 'negative' poles (180° from each other) are created simultaneously.  Those electromagnet forces interact with the rotor's magnet forces to create a torque on the rotor.

Comment: The same thing occurs with the other 2 series-wound stator circuits when they are energized. Since there are 3 series circuits with 4 poles in each circuit, just to be clear, how does that translate properly into your equation/formula to accurately calculate the motor rpm--assuming the ESR output is 1 kHz?

Comment: The motor in the video is a 4-pole motor. The video shows a series of six switch configurations. Proceeding through those six steps creates one cycle of output waveform. If the frequency defined in that manner was 1000 Hz, the speed would be 30,000 RPM. Each individual switch must switch 3 times to complete the sequence. If 1000 Hz is the switching duty of each switch, the speed would be 10,000 RPM. If 1000 Hz is the combined rate of six switches, the speed would be 1667 RPM. If there is switching going on in the middle of a step to control the  voltage & current, hard telling.

Comment: Interesting... so the motor is a "4-pole motor" because 4 magnetic poles are created simultaneously when 1 energy pulse creates them?  I viewed the video again and I noticed that the author states a + pulse from the power supply energizes all 4 A coils to create 2 N poles (180° apart) & 2 S poles (180° apart)--and of course 90° between the N & S poles.  He then states that the same energy pulse goes through the ABC wire junction & into the B coils to energize them before it returns to the power supply.

Comment: That indicates to me that the motor rotates CW due to attractive forces, not repulsive forces.  The remaining pulse steps are:  
2) + pulse from ps to C coils & B coils; 
3) + pulse from ps to C coils & A coils; 
4) + pulse from ps to B coils & A coils; 
5) + pulse from ps to B coils & C coils; 
6) + pulse from ps to A coils & C coils; 

So, wouldn't that be an 8 pole motor if 8 coils are energized with each + pulse from the ps?

Comment: In this design, the coils of two phases combine to form one magnetic pole in each of four positions around the circumference. There is a similar switching scheme that energizes all of the coils simultaneously combining an A, B and C coil to form one magnetic pole. That would be more a sine-wave AC synchronous motor design. I suspect that the two phase combination is more suited to the physical magnet and coil arrangement used here.

Comment: What do you mean by "the coils of two phases"?  It looks like his ESC controller only provides positive current pulses to energize 2 sets of 4 coils (8 coils simultaneously energized for each step in his 6 step cycle) to create a rotating magnetic field within his stator windings.

Comment: Yes. But 2 coils that are next to each other combine to form a single pole even though they are shown as 2N's or 2S's next to each other. Each of the 4 magnets in the rotor is attracted to the nearest pair of coils forming an opposite pole. Note that the controller must cycle twice through the six-step sequence to make the rotor revolve once.

Comment: So, is the motor considered a 4-pole motor because the rotor has 4 magnets that provide 4 poles for torque production OR because 8 energized coils effectively produces 4 poles (i.e. 4 pairs of 2 adjacent poles) for torque production?  I agree that the 6 step cycle must occur twice (i.e. produce 12 total pulses of current) to cause the rotor to make 1 complete revolution. Does that fact have any significant relevance to your formula (Speed (rpm) = 120 * f / p?

Comment: If 12 pulses = 1 rotor revolution, then 1,000 pulses/S = 83.3 rotor r/s = 5,000 rotor r/m. 5k represents 1/6 or 1/2 or 3x your earlier rpm calculation results. What is the right way to arrive at the correct rpm for the motor?

Comment: If an ESC is described as having a 1000 Hz output you can't calculate motor speed unless you know something about the ECS design and how that frequency relates to the specific ESC design. It appears that it is difficult to get detailed information about inexpensive ESCs sold for hobby use. I don't have any experience with hobby products. The industrial products of my experience are similar in principle, but also somewhat different.

Comment: I also don't find many details for such products.  I usually send email to the vendor to get more specifics.  So, alternatively, if I built a variable speed controller, the ratio would be 5:1 (rpm:pulses/S) as I described in my previous comment, correct?

Comment: Yes That definition of pulse frequency works.

Comment: Excellent, thank you!  Now about torque... How does one determine how much torque a coil of a given number of turns will produce when a specific applied voltage will cause a specific current to flow within the coil & how it will interacting with a known magnet (e.g.:  the magnetic forces of a N42 neodymium magnet of given dimensions)?

Comment: That is more that I want to attempt.

Comment: :). Understood. Thank you for all your thoughts & time.